# Python File Handling Script not working when integrating with php

Tags: php, python, shell, file-handling

**shell.php :**

```
<?php
shell_exec("python /opt/lampp/htdocs/web_test/script.py ")
?>
```

**script.py :**

```
fo = open("/opt/lampp/htdocs/web_test/hello.txt", "w")
fo.write( "Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n")
fo.close()
```

Comment: shell.php                                                                                                     <?php    shell_exec("python /opt/lampp/htdocs/web_test/script.py ") ?>

Comment: Try providing the full path to the python binary e.g `/usr/bin/python` and make sure that script.py is readable by the user who will run it (www-data ?)

Comment: yet not working

Comment: Any errors on the PHP end? Also is the `web_test` directory writable ? `is_writable("/opt/lampp/htdocs/web_test")` passes?

Answer (score 0):

check the writing permission

```
is_writable("/opt/lampp/htdocs/web_test")
```